# Trap on DEBUG signal for the Alpine Shell (ash)?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, alpine-linux, ash

With the `bash` shell, you can install a trap on the synthetic DEBUG signal. This is useful and will execute your function or bit of code on every shell command, not so in `ash`, however. E.g.

> $ trap 'echo hi' DEBUG
> -ash: trap: DEBUG: invalid signal specification

How do you trap the DEBUG signal in `ash`?

Comment: I don't think you can. I think DEBUG is a ksh extension that bash adopted. I think ash is intended to be as [pure-POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html) as possible